# What is the best way to check that an Android app is running on windows subsystem for android of windows11?

Tags: android, windows-11

I preparing application for mobile and WSA (Windows Subsystem for Android).

I need to Android app is running on which platforms to develop the application in preparation.

Hardware or CPU architecture is seems to inaccurate.

Any good ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to detect that we are running in a WSA environment is to use the Build class. Examples:

- Build.BRAND will be "Windows"
- Build.BOARD will be "windows"
- Build.MANUFACTURER will be "Microsoft Corporation"
- Build.MODEL will be "Subsystem for Android(TM)"

Comment: These values are from Microsoft's documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/android/wsa/#vm-properties - which also notes "Hardcoding these values is not recommended as that could cause future incompatibilities."